# Dijkstra's Algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I have been practicing different routing exercises and came upon a Dijkstra question which I am unable to decide how to proceed.

[image: Image Here]

My question is which node do i pick first? Since the path is the same: $u-w= 6 $ and $u-x =6.$

Any solutions are appreciated.

Edit: Solution provided by a colleague of mine. Is this the way to go?

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Xr1.png)

Comment: Doesn't matter, the next choice will be the other node.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Although I'm sure the problem setup is clear to you, Readers cannot discern it without a bit more exposition.  What is Dijkstra's (minimal path?) Algorithm tasked with solving?  The first edge chosen depends on where you start and (to a lesser extent) where you are trying to go.

Comment: Hey i edited the post with a solution. Is it Possible to review it? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The first chosen edge doesn't matter -- no matter which one is picked, the other one is picked immediately afterwards. However, if order is really really important to you, you could just assert alphabetical ordering -- tiebreaks happen by alphabetical order.

Comment: Hey i edited the post with a solution. Is it Possible to review it? thanks in advance